# Division Without Using Arithmetic Operator

Tags: c++, loops

I am trying to create a program that performs **INTEGER** division between two numbers. The special thing is that this program will only use increment `++` or decrement `--` operator and loops to perform the division.

```
int quotient = 0; 
while (num1 >= num2) 
{ 
   num1 = num1 - num2 ; 
   quotient++ ; 
}
```

In the above code segment i am using the `-` operator where as I only want to use `++` or `--` (i.e, no arithmetic operator except increment/decrement) to achieve the division between two numbers.

Comment: please elaborate yourself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write a function that implements subtraction by only using `--`

```
int subtract(int a, int b);  // returns a-b
```

Then use that instead of the built-in `operator-`:

```
int quotient = 0; 
while (num1 >= num2) 
{ 
   num1 = subtract(num1,num2); 
   quotient++ ; 
}
```

Comment: Lambda for substract: ````auto subtract = [](int i1, int i2) { while (i2 > 0) { --i1; --i2; } return i1; };```` Lambda for divide: ````auto divide = [&subtract, quotient = 0](int i1, int i2) mutable {while (i1 >= i2) { i1 = subtract(i1, i2); ++quotient; } return quotient; };````

Answer (score 4):

Instead of subtracting num2 from num1 using - operator,
Add one more loop that will run from 1 to num2 and will decrease num1 by 1 using num1--

This will work :

```
int quotient = 0; 
while (num1 >= num2) 
{ 
   for(int i=1;i<=num2;i++){
        num1--;
   }
   quotient++; 
}
```